# Access data with the asp mvc server after sending it to the client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, client-server

In my asp mvc application the client sends a request to the server, where a db request is created and some computations are done to the data from the db. Then the results are sent to the client and displayed.

At this point a button in the client is enabled to allow the user to print a pdf of the chosen data. On the sever a postscript file is filled with the values and transformed into a pdf, which is then printed.

The server needs the data again after sending it to the client, so either I do the db requests and computations again or I send the data from the client to the server.
Right now I just repeat the db request and the computations but both of these options seem very inefficient.

What is the best/regular way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best/regular way to handle this problem?

You can use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so that roundtrips to database will be minimized. So first you save the data in cache, then send it to client. Later when you need to the same data again, then you can just retrieve it from cache and use it. If required, you can also remove that item from cache.

Answer (score 0):

what I believe that client send calls to sever when it requires some response ( data etc) from the server and server is always there to serve requests from the client , and from your question's point of view I think you are doing right , if client doesn't need any thing in response then no need to make a call , it is better to make a db call ( so that to involve only one side for isolation ). Thanks